# Same Django project different GIT repositories

Tags: django, git, repository, django-apps

Which is the best way to have two different repositories on the same Django project?

I started developing a project months ago and I have the whole folder in the repository. I want to reuse some apps in the project and I would like to create a different repository for them since they will be spin-offs project. But I want to keep it updated.

Which is the best workflow, methodology, etc... to achieve this? Or is it a bad approuch?

Thanks!

Xavi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap each app as a python package, which has its own GIT repo. And save all your packages in some private (or public?) python packages repository (like [Gemfury](http://www.gemfury.com/l/pypi-server)).

Then, in your projects, just use the app as you install django itself.. pip install myapp

This way the apps a reusable and decoupled from any project.

(This works very well for myself.. perhaps there is a better way)

Comment: Thanks, I made some research based on your answer and this was exactly what I was looking for :O)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule),

```
$git submodule add git://github.com/yourusername/project2.git project2

$cat .gitmodules
```

.gitmodules output:

```
[submodule "project2"]
  path = project2
  url = git://github.com/yourusername/project2.git
```

If you want to Clone some git project like submodule,

```
git clone git://github.com/yourusername/project2.git
cd project2
git submodule init
```

Comment: I voted up your answer seems it explains how to do part of what I was looking for, but @YardenST answer solves exactly the question. Thanks!